# Jumbotron like boxes behind thumbnails in using Bootstrap

Tags: css, image, border

I'm just starting to work with Bootstrap and I've run into a problem I can't seem to find a proper solution for, without downloading the whole bootstrap system and editing it locally.

I'm just messing around, seeing what I can do and I've lined up some random pictures from my pc in a grid, but theres a solid box behind them. I can't work out a way to get rid of them with CSS.

```css
.thumbnail {
  border: 0 none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle-section">
          <div class="container">
           <h2>Just the middle section</h2>
           <p>Just typing some bullshit to fill in the extra space, just gonna put in some random pictues from my computer</p>

          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="mario.png">
            </div>

            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="businesssloth.png">
            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="ohface.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="nerdpug.jpg">
            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="5.jpg">
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```css
.thumbnail {
  border: 0 none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="middle-section">
          <div class="container">
           <h2>Just the middle section</h2>
           <p>Just typing some bullshit to fill in the extra space, just gonna put in some random pictues from my computer</p>

          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAALTAAAAJGY1NGY1N2ZhLTNmZmUtNGRmZi1iMDgxLTJjZjdkNjNkYmZlOQ.png">
            </div>

            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAALTAAAAJGY1NGY1N2ZhLTNmZmUtNGRmZi1iMDgxLTJjZjdkNjNkYmZlOQ.png">
            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAALTAAAAJGY1NGY1N2ZhLTNmZmUtNGRmZi1iMDgxLTJjZjdkNjNkYmZlOQ.png">
            </div>

            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAALTAAAAJGY1NGY1N2ZhLTNmZmUtNGRmZi1iMDgxLTJjZjdkNjNkYmZlOQ.png">
            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAALTAAAAJGY1NGY1N2ZhLTNmZmUtNGRmZi1iMDgxLTJjZjdkNjNkYmZlOQ.png">
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set border to `0px` instead of setting to `none`

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.thumbnail{
    border:0px !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
   -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
   box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle-section">
          <div class="container">
           <h2>Just the middle section</h2>
           <p>Just typing some bullshit to fill in the extra space, just gonna put in some random pictues from my computer</p>

          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="mario.png">
            </div>

            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="businesssloth.png">
            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="ohface.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="nerdpug.jpg">
            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="5.jpg">
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```